# How to create Extract Button in Tableau Dashboard for directly extracting data into CSV file without publishing the Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

How to create Extract Button in Tableau Dashboard for directly extracting data into CSV file without publishing the Dashboard??

""I have not published by dashboard.""

Requirement:
Click on image kind of button on Dashboard and it will extract data for user without giving access to all data, it is similar to download option in any application.

Answer (score 0):

A while back, I ran across an article on VizWiz about extracts that I though was a pretty elegant solution: [Exporting CSV made simple](http://www.vizwiz.com/2014/03/the-greatest-tableau-tip-ever-exporting.html)

The only issue is that it probably doesn't work directly on Desktop but requires the workbook to be published. However, it might give you some ideas on whether it might work for a Reader environment.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a download button with an unpublished data-source and dashboard as there would not be anything to download. In order to have a download button working you need to have published both data and dashboard to download.

Once published, you can download the CSV of the data although you may need to reformat it.  The steps are here:
https://www.dataplusscience.com/UpdatedURLs.html

and the basic formula for the link creation is:

`https://[Tableau Server]/views/[Workbook Name]/[Worksheet Name].csv`

If it is for your own use, and you are trying to use Tableau Desktop to clean/manipulate the data, you are almost certainly better off using Tableau Prep for this as you can determine the format and shape before create a custom data extract. If you are not planning to reformat the data you can export the data as a csv file in the Data Source tab of Tableau Desktop. Go to Data (top left of screen)> 'Export to csv'